# Run OpenGL window besides Tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, tkinter, glfw

I am trying to open :

- on one hand, an OpenGL window, using `glfw`
- on the other hand, a GUI window, using `tkinter`

However, both are run with a blocking call for them to render:

- glfw: `while not glfw.window_should_close(window): ...`
- Tkinter: `self.ui_root.mainloop()`

Would you know a way to circumvent that, and to allow to have both windows open at the same time, accepting Keyboard/Mouse events?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to show any research at all, which is something StackOverflow encourages before asking a question.

Comment: well to be honest I ask this question because my researches led me to no solution.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what you've researched and what you've tried unless you tell us.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the tkinter window on a keyboard event, you have to write a callback function to do this. Suppose, if you press "T" then the tkinter window will be showed up. According to your question it will run `self.ui_root.mainloop()`. Here, the basic structure of your code will be this:

```py
#callback function
def key_input_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mode):
    if key == glfw.KEY_T and action == glfw.PRESS:
        self.ui_root.mainloop()

#display loop
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    ....
    ....
    glfw.set_key_callback(self.window, key_input_callback)
    ....
    ....
```

Here, the callback function receives the keyboard key and the action, and perform what you want it to do. The action is one of `glfw.PRESS`, `glfw.REPEAT`, or `glfw.RELEASE`.